# How to copy svn directory with all files and subdirectories by file?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We have a huge svn repository. We need to copy one directory with all subdirectories and NOT ALL files into another place, basically to create a branch, but we need to exclude many files while copying. I thought about copying the whole directory using TortoiseSVN mouse right click and drag and drop and then going through the created copy and doing "undo add" to the files I don't want to see there and then commit the branch but the problem is that some files were copied individually with this method and they can be "undo add" but other files are like linked to a group of files and/or the parent directory and they cannot be "undo add" individually. I can only "undo add" the whole group.

Is is possible to copy such a way that all files are copied independently and could be "undo add" individually? Is there a way to maybe break that files/parent directory link and still do "undo add" individually after mouse right click drag and drop?

Answer (score 0):

Use remove instead undo add:

```
svn rm path/to/unwanted/file
```

Comment: Not the same with what I actually need. From the SVN repository perspective deletion is far not the same as not adding. If I merge this branch later on, deletion will be executed on the trunk or wherever I merge to, not adding will not affect the target branch, which is what I want.

Comment: If you have same directory in trunk, then both solutions will brings tree conflicts. If you don't have same directory, then both approaches will works equally good.

Comment: Hm. May be I do not understand initial question. Do you want to create *branch* but have in it only subset of files, work on them and then merge back to trunk only this subset? In this case, I think here is no solution.

Comment: Yes. This is exactly the case. I found a way which definitely not efficient. Export versioned files into the branch directory (working copy), then remove what I don't need and then add the rest. After commit I have a single add operation for multiple files and if I later on merge this branch into the trunk it merges the changes since adding files. The only thing that bothers me is that the whole copy of files is added.

Comment: `if I later on merge this branch into the trunk it merges the changes since adding files` just in case if you not aware: this will be baseless merge which will require more efforts.